# Calculating bone transformation matrix for vertex skinning

Tags: matrix, glm

I have an issue with calculating transformation matrices for animation mesh deformation using glm in c++

I have a class Bone which does the basic calculation which does have a current local position (vec3) and local roation (quaternion) and also the bind local position and rotation.
After loading the skeleton i call the following method for the root bone:

```cpp
void Bone::calculateBindTransform(glm::mat4 parentBindTransform) {
    _localBindTransform = glm::translate(_localBindTransform, getStartPosition());
    _localBindTransform *= glm::mat4_cast(getStartQuaternion());

    _bindTransform = glm::translate(parentBindTransform, getStartPosition());
    _bindTransform *= glm::mat4_cast(getStartQuaternion());
    _inverseBindTransform = glm::inverse(_bindTransform);

    for(auto &child: getChildren()) {
        child->calculateBindTransform(_bindTransform);
    }
}
```

Than I have the following method to calculate the model space transform of the current bone state:

```cpp
glm::mat4 Bone::getTransform() const {
    glm::mat4 transform{1.0f};
    auto parent = getParent().lock();
    if(parent) {
        transform = parent->getTransform();
    }

    transform = glm::translate(transform, getPosition());
    transform *= glm::mat4_cast(getQuaternion());

    return transform;
}
```

For debugging I currently render cubes for every bone using the transform, that works fine and the skeleton looks how it's suppose to look.
Currently I would pass to the shader the following matrix for every bone: `getTransform() * _inverseBindTransform`. But as soon as I move a single bone out of the bind pose the mesh gets totally destroyed.
To test if that works I changed the rendering of the debug cubes to the following transform `_bindTransform * getTransform() * _inverseBindTransform` which I expected to work but the skeleton than breaks as soon as I change the root bone too.

This is how the debug cubes look like with the bind pose: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAdkq.jpg
But when I change the root bone's y to 50 instead of 0 the skeleton kinda explodes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuFcN.jpg

I guess I have a logic problem somewhere but I'm too blind to see it